# Is Velocity.js abandoned/unmaintained?

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity.js

### Preface

I've found anime.js, which not only has far better documentation than Velocity.js, but also has sequencing out of the box, and just works. I am moving to that library, but I'll keep this up in case someone can come through with an explanation as to why this isn't working for me.

### Original

I keep hitting issues trying to get Velocity.js and Velocity UI to work. I'm just using a vanilla jQuery environment, no node, no angular, nothing complicated.

The documentation for Velocity is so fragmented that I've found three or four processes for calling the sequence feature in Velocity UI, but none of them work.

I load jQuery, then Velocity, then Velocity UI, and I can console log objects specific to each one to confirm they've loaded, and are in order.

```
    <!-- JQuery -->
       <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
            rel="preload">
       </script>
    <!-- Scripts -->
       <script src="./inc/scripts/app/lib/velocity.min.js"></script>
       <script src="./inc/scripts/app/lib/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
```

The following is the only process that doesn't throw an error, but it literally does nothing...

```
    $div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

    $.Velocity.Sequences.hover = function (element, options) {
        var duration = options.duration || 750;

        $.Velocity.animate(element,
            { 
            top: "-=10px",
            }, { 
            /* Delay is relative to user-adjustable duration. */
            delay: duration * 0.033,
            duration: duration,
            loop: 3,
            easing: "easeInOutSine"
            });
    };

    $div.velocity("hover");
```

It does nothing at all. The objects are there, the 'hover' function exists within the Velocity.Sequences object. But I can't seem to make it work.

Am I doing this wrong? I tried doing it with $.Velocity AND Velocity, trying to bypass jQuery, so I'm pretty sure it's not a jquery compatibility issue.

Is Velocity just unmaintained?

If it's the latter, is there a new library that's stepped up to replace it? I tried transit, and it works, but I was really interested in Velocity UI's sequence feature.

### Edit

I was asked to include a snippet of the non-working code. The following uses code from [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/improving-ui-animation-workflow-velocity-js/), which was linked to within the Velocity UI documentation, and is the only method of working with sequences I've found that doesn't throw an error.

Here is the code targeting a node list...

```js
$div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

$.Velocity.Sequences.hover = function(element, options) {
  var duration = options.duration || 750;

  $.Velocity.animate(element, {
    translateY: "-=10px",
  }, {
    /* Delay is relative to user-adjustable duration. */
    delay: duration * 0.033,
    duration: duration,
    loop: 3,
    easing: "easeInOutSine"
  });
};

$div.velocity("hover");
```

```css
#box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
</body>
```

Here is a snippet targeting a jQuery object $('div')

```js
$.Velocity.Sequences.hover = function(element, options) {
  var duration = options.duration || 750;

  $.Velocity.animate(element, {
    translateY: "-=10px",
  }, {
    /* Delay is relative to user-adjustable duration. */
    delay: duration * 0.033,
    duration: duration,
    loop: 3,
    easing: "easeInOutSine"
  });
};

$('div').velocity('hover');
```

```css
#box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='box'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

and a snippet targeting the jQuery object $('#box')...

```js
$.Velocity.Sequences.hover = function(element, options) {
  var duration = options.duration || 750;

  $.Velocity.animate(element, {
    translateY: "-=10px",
  }, {
    /* Delay is relative to user-adjustable duration. */
    delay: duration * 0.033,
    duration: duration,
    loop: 3,
    easing: "easeInOutSine"
  });
};

$('#box').velocity('hover');
```

```css
#box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: silver;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/velocity-animate@2.0/velocity.ui.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='box'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well the last commit on the git project was Aug 2020, so yea, won't be that up-to-date.

Comment: I was hoping it was a case that the last release just worked so well it didn't need to be updated. xD But I guess that was too optimistic.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for errors? `$div` in the code you posted is a browser node list object, not a jQuery object. I doubt very much that `$div.velocity()` will work, and I suspect it's an error.

Comment: @Pointy do you use Velocity UI? The feature I'm trying to use is from that plugin. 

And the $div bit was copied exactly from a tutorial linked from the Velocity documentation, and there are no errors in the console.

Comment: I've never heard of "Velocity UI" and at present I cannot find any reference to it on the internet. Generally something like your `$div` variable would be initialized as a jQuery object, not a node list.

Comment: Specifically, with `$` being the jQuery entry point, `$("div")` is absolutely not the same as `getElementsByTagName("div")`.

Comment: @Pointy You can find the UI pack on the github page of Velocity.js. You can find documentation on the pack on Velocity's main site. 

I have tried both the node list $div, and I have tried the jQuery object $("div"), and I have tried targeting a specific div with $('#id'). I have tried to target an element by using vanilla getElementById(). Nothing is working, and there are no errors.

Comment: It would help a lot if you would ammend your question to include a sample of the code not working. I know for a fact that the library does in fact work.

Comment: @Pointy I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean by 'to include a sample of the code not working'. I did include a sample of the code that isn't working.

Comment: A Stack snippet. This site has a facility like Codepen to allow actual operating code in questions.

Comment: @Pointy I have added three snippets of code, targeting the element in different ways. None work, none show an error. I can successfully log the necessary objects in every one, so they're loaded, they're there. I'm just not able to actually call the sequence function.

Comment: Probably the fundamental problem here is that when you call `$div.velocity("hover")` none of your code is run; nothing happens at all. The library is clearly there, but that way of invoking your "hover" sequence is apparently incorrect.

Comment: @Pointy I can't seem to find the correct way to do it. Every other example I've found, including every example in the documentation, throws an error telling me the UI object/function the example uses has not been defined. I'm going to try anime.js The documentation is way more reliable from what I've seen. Thanks for your help.